# SSL based JMX RMI cannot be connected with Jconsole

Tags: ssl, rmi, jmx, jconsole

Nowadays, I'm trying to enable both `SSL` and `password` authentication for my JMX agent according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdemv .

I've tried according to IBM knowledge base article https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSJJ9R_5.0.1/com.ibm.jazz.repository.web.admin.doc/topics/t_server_mon_tomcat_option3.html .

I've even tried to enable `HTTPS` for my embed tomcat in my tiny `Spring Boot` application as following:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: ${java.home}\\lib\\management\\jmxrmi-server.jks
    key-password: -P@ssw0rd
    trust-store: ${java.home}\\lib\\management\\jmxrmi-trust.jks
    trust-store-password: -P@ssw0rd
  port: 443
```

Actually, I've done this step by step as following:

Generate tow `keystore`s for JMX server and JConsole:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -keysize 2048 -keystore server.jks -alias server
keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -keysize 2048 -keystore client.jks -alias client
keytool -exportcert -keystore server.jks -file server.cer -alias server
keytool -exportcert -keystore client.jks -file client.cer -alias client
keytool -importcert -keystore server.jks -file client.cer -alias client
keytool -importcert -keystore client.jks -file server.cer -alias server
```

Start JMX sample application:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\\programs\\jdk1.8.0_144\\jre\\lib\\management\\server.jks \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456 \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\\programs\\jdk1.8.0_144\\jre\\lib\\management\\server.jks \
-jar example-jmx/target/example-jmx-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Start JConsole:

```
jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 \
-J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\\programs\\jdk1.8.0_144\\jre\\lib\\management\\client.jks \
-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456 \
-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\\programs\\jdk1.8.0_144\\jre\\lib\\management\\client.jks \
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:1099/jmxrmi
```

And it finally complains as following:

[image]

Translation of this message is:

**Failed to connect to the server securely. Should we retry insecurely?**

**Unable to connect to *service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:1099/jmxrmi*. Do you want to retry without SSL?(Username and password will be sent in plaintext.)**

I've checked sun's manual about monitoring and management using JMX in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdemv and it turns out to be another failure. I've no idea where I am wrong and how to fix this.

**Any suggestion would be appreciate!**

Comment: Check out this link. http://www.cleantutorials.com/jconsole/jconsole-ssl-with-password-authentication

Comment: @AbhinavP Thanks! I've checked what I've done according to the article and temporarily not found the reason why my circumstance not work. I'll check it later. Thanks anyway!

Comment: okay. Try starting JConsole with debug logs enabled, maybe that will help. And also check in your logs, if the truststore and keystore were loaded on both sides.